# Calling fswebcam through apache / python script

Tags: python

I am running the following command in my python script:

```
res = subprocess.Popen(["fswebcam", "-r 640x480", "grab.jpeg"], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, cwd="/var/www/pics");
output = res.communicate()[0];
```

which runs fine when calling the script manually.

But when running the script through apache, I get no error message but no image appears in the /var/www/pics directory. This directory as been assigned to www-data:www-data and has the write permissions.

I don't understand what I am missing to get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the issue, the www-data user was not allowed to run fswebcam, so I added a coniguration file in the /etc/sudoers.d directory to allow access to fswebcam by user www-data.

Here is the content of my file:

> Defaults:www-data !requiretty
>
> %www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/fswebcam

I also had to modify the call to fswebcam in my python script by adding "sudo" as begginning of the command.

> res = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "fswebcam", "-r 640x480", "grab.jpeg"], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, cwd="/var/www/pics");